# How to fully test Django ImportMixin via excel

Tags: django, excel, selenium, unit-testing, django-import-export

I have an admin model that uses django-import-export via an excel file typically. I want to test it as thoroughly as I can. I can test the file format & headers should be as expected, as well as the widgets used by the resource that controls the import validation. However, I do some changes to the data when its saved & imported, I can't figure out how to test that with the below method or via selenium since it involves an excel file. Tips? I would just like to test that when we import via excel, the things I do in the resource take effect, namely I upload users & add them to groups, but the test method below only tests the dataset is properly setup, it doesn't create any records. I also use Selenium to test user functionality, but didn't find how I could mimic an excel file.

```
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin

class CustomUserAdmin(ImportMixin, UserAdmin):
    # this resource controls the custom checks for the import mixin
    resource_class = UserResource
```

A snippet of the resource I use, uses several widgets to control validation

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
id = fields.Field(column_name='id', attribute='id')  # only here to keep the id on the left, preference
username = fields.Field(widget=UsernameWidget(), column_name='username', attribute='username')
# we use a custom field, so we can hash the password without showing it to the user
user_password = fields.Field(widget=PasswordWidget(), column_name='user_password', attribute='user_password')
email = fields.Field(widget=RequiredWidget(), column_name='email', attribute='email')
first_name = fields.Field(column_name='first_name', attribute='first_name')
last_name = fields.Field(column_name='last_name', attribute='last_name')
role = fields.Field(widget=RoleWidget(), column_name='role', attribute='role')

class Meta:
    model = User
    exclude = ('last_login', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'password', 'groups', 'is_staff',)
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'user_password', 'email', 'role', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

Here's a snippet of how I test some of the validation/widgets

```
    def test_role_must_be_one_of_3_choices(self):
    rows = [
        [1, 'username', 'user_password', 'email@email.com', 'admin', '', ''],
        [1, 'username1', 'user_password', 'email@email.com', 'competitor', '', ''],
        [1, 'username2', 'user_password', 'email@email.com', 'judge', '', ''],
        [1, 'username3', 'user_password', 'email@email.com', 'wrong', '', ''],
    ]

    dataset = tablib.Dataset(*rows, headers=self.headers)
    result = self.resource.import_data(
        dataset, dry_run=True, use_transactions=True,
        collect_failed_rows=True,
    )
    # we should get 1 good row & 1 failed row
    self.assertEqual(len(result.failed_dataset), 1)
    self.assertEqual(len(result.valid_rows()), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the latest [v3 branch](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/tree/release-3-x/tests/core/tests).  There are lots of example tests.  I suggest you would want [unit tests](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/c766284140c79d7fb2b3661860f52f3ca8a43b3f/tests/core/tests/test_widgets.py#L27) for your custom widgets, and integration tests for your end-to-end logic.

The source itself includes [integration tests](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/c766284140c79d7fb2b3661860f52f3ca8a43b3f/tests/core/tests/test_admin_integration.py#L231) which load data from a source file (e.g. Excel), and process it via import.  You could adapt this to read from a source file, do your import, and then read objects back directly from the db to ensure that they are in the correct state.

Ensure you test with the [v3 beta](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/3.0.0b1/) as this will become the latest version of the library in the next month or so.